# How to have the same random results

Tags: javascript, html, random, p5.js

Im trying to write a program that generate random pairs(without repetition), it would be used
for my family to shuffle who would get who for giving him/her Christmas gift :)
I want to have one, random result and send it to 6 different people, however, whenever someone is loading a page, it randomize results.
I want to be able to shuffle it once, and then send the link for everyone to see their pair.
How can i separate randomizing from reloading a code?

my code so far (im starting learning .js)

```
let irena
let jola;
let maciek;
let marta;
let ula;
let lukasz;

let jola_2
let maciek_2
let marta_2
let irena_2
let ula_2
let lukasz_2

var names = ["lukasz", "jola", "ula", "maciek", "marta", "irena"]

var guziki = []
var obrazki = []

var arr1 = names.slice(),
  arr2 = names.slice(); 



function preload(){
  irena = loadImage('irena.png');
  jola = loadImage('jola.png');
  maciek = loadImage('maciek.png');
  marta = loadImage('marta.png');
  ula = loadImage('ula.png');
  lukasz = loadImage('lukasz.png');  
}


arr1.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
});

arr2.sort(function() {
  return 0.5 - Math.random();
});


while (arr1.length) {
  var name1 = arr1.pop(),
    name2 = arr2[0] == name1 ? arr2.pop() : arr2.shift();
  guziki.push(name1)
  obrazki.push(name2)
}

//szukanie gdzie kto
const found_irena = guziki.findIndex(element => element === "irena")
const found_jola = guziki.findIndex(element => element === "jola")
const found_maciek = guziki.findIndex(element => element === "maciek")
const found_marta = guziki.findIndex(element => element === "marta")
const found_ula = guziki.findIndex(element => element === "ula")
const found_lukasz = guziki.findIndex(element => element === "lukasz")


function linia(){
  //irena
  line(140,70,280,70); //prosta
  line(200,50,280,70); //strzalka gorna
  line(200,90,280,70); //strzalka dolna
  //jola
  line(140,170,280,170);
  line(200,150,280,170);
  line(200,190,280,170);
  //maciek
   line(140,270,280,270);
  line(200,250,280,270);
  line(200,290,280,270);
  //marta
   line(140,370,280,370);
  line(200,350,280,370);
  line(200,390,280,370);
  //ula
   line(140,470,280,470);
  line(200,450,280,470);
  line(200,490,280,470);
  //lukasz
   line(140,570,280,570);
  line(200,550,280,570);
  line(200,590,280,570);
}


function setup() {
  createCanvas(400, 800);
}

function draw() {
  background(200,200,0);
  linia();
  image(irena,20,20,irena.width/10,irena.height/10);
  image(jola,20,120,jola.width/10,jola.height/10);
  image(maciek,20,220,maciek.width/11,maciek.height/11);
  image(marta,20,320,marta.width/12,marta.height/12);
  image(ula,20,420,ula.width/10,ula.height/10);
  image(lukasz,20,520,lukasz.width/10,lukasz.height/10);
  if (irena_2 >0){
    textSize(30)
    text(obrazki[found_irena], 300, 75);
    fill(40,100,100);
  } else if(jola_2 >0){
    textSize(30)
    text(obrazki[found_jola], 300, 175);
    fill(40,100,100);
  }else if(maciek_2 >0){
    textSize(30)
    text(obrazki[found_maciek], 300, 275);
    fill(40,100,100);
  }
  else if(marta_2 >0){
    textSize(30)
    text(obrazki[found_marta], 300, 375);
    fill(40,100,100);
  }
  else if(ula_2 >0){
    textSize(30)
    text(obrazki[found_ula], 300, 475);
    fill(40,100,100);
  }
  else if(lukasz_2 >0){
    textSize(30)
    text(obrazki[found_lukasz], 300, 575);
    fill(40,100,100);
  }
    
}

function mousePressed() {
  if (mouseY >20 && mouseY<120 && mouseX > 20 && mouseX<120) {
    console.log("kliknales irenke" + "a ona wylosowala ");
    irena_2 =1;
  } else if (mouseY >120 && mouseY<220 && mouseX > 20 && mouseX<120){
    console.log("kliknales jolke a ona wylosowala ")
    jola_2 =1;
  } else if (mouseY >220 && mouseY<320 && mouseX > 20 && mouseX<120){
    console.log("kliknales macka a on wylosowal")
    maciek_2 =1;
  } else if (mouseY >320 && mouseY<420 && mouseX > 20 && mouseX<120){
    console.log("kliknales marte")
    marta_2=1;
  } else if (mouseY >420 && mouseY<520 && mouseX > 20 && mouseX<120){
    console.log("kliknales ule")
    ula_2= 1;
  } else if (mouseY >520 && mouseY<620 && mouseX > 20 && mouseX<120){
    console.log("kliknales lukaszka")
    lukasz_2 =1;
  }
  
}
```

thank you in advance,
Lukasz

Comment: Well you can take the random order in through the url as a [query string](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string), and if no query string is present, display a button to randomize the order and copy the new link.

Answer (score 0):

As you are already using p5, you could also use p5's [`random()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/random) function (instead of `Math.random()`) to produce random numbers. You can "fix" the sequence of random numbers by providing a random "seed" using p5's [`randomSeed()`](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/randomSeed) function (see the example in the [documentation](https://p5js.org/reference/#/p5/randomSeed)). Depending on the random seed, it will always produce the same pseudo-random result, no matter where and when your app is used.

If that's "not random enough" for you, you could, for example, specify the random seed itself by setting it to a true random value from https://www.random.org/ :)

Comment: Thank you for your useful tip Sir, problem solved! :)